# Qual è il significato di "gabola" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, regional

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te*, di Paola Mastrocola, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Quanto a lui, faceva esattamente le stesse cose di tutti i giorni, solo che non le faceva in ufficio ma all'aperto, magari sotto un albero o ai bordi della piscina, con la sua polo color pastello e uno dei costumi a fiori che gli comprava sua moglie: sbrigava la corrispondenza (elettronica e cartacea), sfogliava i maggiori quotidiani (italiani ed esteri), imbastiva lo schema di certe nuove pratiche, si studiava meglio certe *gabole* legali insidiose, e a volte, proprio quando si voleva concedere il massimo di libertà, si leggiucchiava avidamente i numeri arretrati di certe sue riviste giuridiche.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "gabola" in alcuni dizionari: la spiegazione più dettagliata l'ho trovata nel
[Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/G/gabola.shtml). Comunque, nessuno dei significati elencati lì sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "gabola" nella frase precedente?

Comment: Sul De Mauro c'è: [gabola](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/gabola).

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG, ma la definizione in questo dizionario è simile ai sensi figurati spiegati nel dizionario Hoepli. Comunque, ho cambiato il testo della domanda.

Comment: Giusto. E perché non ti convince? Evidentemente il personaggio sta studiando certi cavilli legali, modi al limite del lecito per sfruttare la lettera della legge. Per completezza, anche lo Zingarelli – non accessibile gratuitamente – riporta una definizione similissima («piccolo imbroglio, raggiro») ma con marca “sett.” anziché “centrosett.” E in effetti, a me personalmente, romano, suona più settentrionale.

Comment: ...come spiegare ad uno straniero quanto sia intricato il codice italiano?

Comment: @DaG: Capisco, grazie! Potresti metterlo come risposta?

Comment: @Charo: D'accordo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In effetti non tutti i dizionari lo riportano. Quelli che lo fanno, come il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/gabola) e lo Zingarelli (non accessibile gratuitamente) lo definiscono, parola più parola meno, come «bugia, frottola | intrigo, imbroglio». Direi che qui il personaggio stia studiando certi cavilli legali lievemente loschi, modi al limite del lecito per sfruttare la lettera della legge.

Aggiungo che il De Mauro dà come marca “centrosett.”, mentre lo Zingarelli lo definisce solo “sett.”, e a me personalmente, che sono romano, suona più settentrionale.

Comment: Aggiungo come commento perché la risposta è comunque adeguata. Da persona del nord Italia io ho sempre usato *gabola* per indicare trucchi tecnicamente nel rispetto delle norme (siano esse le leggi dello stato o qualche altra forma di regole vigenti in un contesto sociale) ma che vanno abbastanza chiaramente contro lo spirito di esse. Ad esempio una mossa che è tecnicamente nel rispetto delle regole di un gioco da tavolo, ma che gli autori non avevano immaginato e che non rispetta l'idea di come esso dovrebbe essere giocato. O, più banalmente, trucchi per dichiarare meno tasse ;).

Answer (score 2):

Ecco la definizione di "gabola" che appare sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI23/00424.jpg):

> **Gàbola,** sf. Bugia, frottola. – Anche: intrigo, imbroglio; scap­patoia, sotterfugio. 
>  
>         
>   *Bianciardi*, 1-219:  Ne  uscì  il  ‘governo  vivo’  che  abbiamo  oggi,  così rinnovato,  così  diverso  rispetto  alle  gabole  partitiche  del  passato. 
>   *U. Simonetta*, 1-45: Deve aver mangiato la foglia che c’è sotto una gabola. 
>  
>         = Voce centrosett., propr. var. di *cabala*, v. anche *gabbolare*.

Il significato più adatto al contesto del brano citato nella domanda è quello di "sotterfugio": il personaggio di cui parla il testo si dedicava a studiare certe stratagemme legali insidiose.

Come il De Mauro, questo dizionario lo definisce come "voce centrosettentrionale". 
Leggendo il contenuto dell'entrata ["gabbolare"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000528.jpg) è interessante vedere che provviene dal lombardo *gabolà*.

Comment: _Gabola_ è una parola piuttosto comune nel dialetto piemontese, e in Piemonte si sente abbastanza. Paola Mastrocola è infatti una scrittrice piemontese.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Vuoi dire che, come ha scritto DaG nella sua risposta, sarebbe più giusto dire che è "settentrionale" e non "centrosettentrionale"?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano:  Potresti dare un'occhiata a [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/6342)? Penso sia stata un po' messa in dubbio e, infatti, io non l'ho accettata fino a quando non ho letto *La malora* anni dopo.

Comment: Sì, _gabola_ la definirei più settentrionale che centrosettentrionale. Nota che pur essendo molto comune in Piemonte potrebbe non essere di origine piemontese. [Questo sito](http://www.piemunteis.it/) ha un dizionario piemontese recente che la riporta, ma ha anche dei [dizionari dell '800](http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber) (sulla colonna di destra) che non la riportano. Quindi potrebbe essere stata introdotta più recentemente, magari effettivamente importata dal lombardo.

Comment: La stessa cosa per _sversa_, che significa anche _ubriaca_: è comune in piemontese, ma se si guardano quei dizionari dell'800, non è presente.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano:   Finalmente ho trovato sul GDLI che ["sverso"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11425) è di origine piemontese! (quanti anni nel dubbio!). Il problema era che inserendo "sverso" sul cercatore del GDLI non si trova, si deve scrivere "svèrso" con l'accento!

Comment: Allora devono decisamente migliorare la funzione di ricerca!