# Come si può rendere "buscador" in italiano? (nell'ambito dell'informatica)

Tags: word-choice, translation, phrase-request

In un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11421/707) ho scritto "cercatore" per riferirmi a un'applicazione informatica disegnata per ricercare informazione su internet o su un determinato sito internet tramite l'inserimento di una o più parole. Ma poi ho avuto la sensazione che questo non fosse il termine che si usa in italiano per quel concetto. L'ho fatto per influenza del vocabolo catalano ["cercador"](https://dlc.iec.cat/Results?IdE=0049816&DecEntradaText=cercador&AllInfoMorf=False&OperEntrada=0&OperDef=0&OperEx=0&OperSubEntrada=0&OperAreaTematica=0&InfoMorfType=0&OperCatGram=False&AccentSen=False&CurrentPage=0&refineSearch=0) e di quello castigliano ["buscador"](https://dle.rae.es/buscador?m=form), che sono i termini che si usano in queste lingue per tale concetto. La mia domanda è: come devo esprimerlo in italiano? La terminologia a usare è "funzione di ricerca" come ha fatto Massimo Ortolano nel suo commento? O esiste qualche altro vocabolo più adatto?

Comment: Credo che nel contesto vada bene "funzione di ricerca" visto che si parla di un sistema informatico. "Motore di ricerca" o "algoritmo di ricerca" sono più tecnici e pongono più attenzione sullo strumento che sul risultato. "Cercatore" lo vedo più come una professione che che una funzione. Per cui, per rispondere, la terminologia da usare credo sia quella da te proposta: "funzione di ricerca".

Comment: "Cercatore" a me fa venire in mente qualcuno che vaga nei boschi per funghi e castagne, sarebbe bello si diffondesse anche in quest'àmbito ma al momento direi proprio che non si usa :) Io userei motore di ricerca, di solito se usato senza contesto si sottintende che si riferisca a motori di ricerca Internet (come Google), ma può riferirsi anche a motori di ricerca interni a siti o applicazioni a sé stanti.

Comment: @OldManofAran: Potresti scriverlo come risposta, per favore?

Comment: @ChristianL.: Potresti scriverlo come risposta, per favore?

Answer (score 3):

Il [dizionario Spagnolo-Italiano di Zanichelli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_spagnolo/Spagnolo/B/buscador.shtml) riporta:

> **buscador** 
> **s.m.** (inform.)
>
> motore **m.** di ricerca

[Il Grande dizionario Hoepli spagnolo](https://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Spagnolo-Italiano/parola/B/buscador.aspx?query=buscador) invece propone

> **buscador** (-a)
>  \buskaDór\ *[adj]* cercatore (f -trice).

Quella di Zanichelli sembra la terminologia più adatta, perché "cercatore" è un termine generico e non viene usato in ambito informatico.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che nel contesto indicato nella domanda vada bene "**funzione di ricerca**", visto che si parla di un sistema informatico. 
"**Motore di ricerca**" o "**algoritmo di ricerca**" sono più tecnici e pongono più attenzione sullo strumento che sul risultato.  
"**Cercatore**" è usato più per indicare una professione che una funzione.  
Per cui, per rispondere, la terminologia da usare credo sia quella da te proposta: "***funzione di ricerca***".