# Cosa significa e dove si usa l'espressione "all'ultimo tuffo"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> È una donna sveglia e coraggiosa, ma non l'ho capita quando sosteneva d'aver avuto l'impressione d'una società non politica e regolata dal silenzio del governo e da quello del popolo. L'ho spedita dagli antifascisti politicamente più attivi poiché ci riempiva di domande troppo specifiche e di taglio marxistico: quale sviluppo... quali salari... quanta classe operaia... relazioni tra capitale catalano e spagnolo. E peccato che Sacristán **all'ultimo tuffo** si fosse ammalato, ché magari lui era in grado di soddisfarla...

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "all'ultimo tuffo" che appare in questo brano? Si tratta di un modo di dire? L'ho cercata alla voce "tuffo" di parecchi dizionari, incluso il Dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovata. Da una ricerca su Google mi è sembrato capire che si tratta di un'espressione che si usa abbastanza.

Per esempio, in questo *Calendario dei visacci* del 1938, pubblicato da Vallecchi, si può leggere:

> Un'autentica delizia; per fortuna si può rimediare. Ed eccoti, dopo una serie di alti e bassi scoraggianti, al 21 del mese e, trascorsa una giornata di semi-agitazione, alle nove di sera, all'ora cioè temuta e desiderata. Hai tentato, **all'ultimo tuffo**, di leggere la tua roba per la ennesima volta, ma hai rinunziato immediatamente alla prova considerando che, fra le pareti domestiche​, era impossibile crearsi lo « stato d'animo » necessario per prendere contatto con gli ascoltatori invisibili. Pazienza! Sarà come Dio vorrà.

E anche nel libro [*In nome del Figlio*](https://books.google.es/books?id=IQKKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&dq=%22all%27ultimo+tuffo%22+nome&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl3u_n893nAhUGYxoKHRMRAAkQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22all'ultimo%20tuffo%22%20nome&f=false), di Emanuele Berni, si trova:

> Se il Salvatore nacque in una grotta due possono essere le ipotesi: la prima escatologico/dimostrativa indicherebbe un segnale forte per mostrare all'umanità come il Figlio di Dio, Signore del cielo  e della terra, scelga tra tutti per nascere un umile giaciglio di paglia in una grotta umida, affermando così solennemente la sua vicinanza ai poveri  e ai derelitti, la seconda, meno immaginifica e più pedestremente laica ci riporta a un Giuseppe improvvido che decide solo **all'ultimo tuffo** di mettersi in cammino per​ Betlemme, nonostante che il censimento  fosse stato notificato molto tempo prima dai messi dell'​imperatore.

Dai contesti di questi esempi, direi che il senso sia qualcosa come "all'ultimo momento", ma forse l'espressione ha qualche sfumatura che mi sfugge.

Inoltre, sapresti dirmi dove si usa questa espressione? Si tratta forse di un modo di dire toscano? Luti, Vallecchi e Berni sono o erano fiorentini. E l'unico non nato a Firenze 
tra gli autori citati nella mia risposta è Giuseppe Antonio Borgese, che però studiò e visse a Firenze (infatti morì a Fiesole).

Comment: Nella ricerca che ho fatto, lo vedo usato tanto nei commenti sportivi; non lo conosco, però, come modo di dire nella quotidianità. L’idea, comunque, è quella che hai indicato nella domanda: «all’ultimo (momento)», «proprio alla fine».

Comment: Forse è un'espressione toscana: https://books.google.es/books?id=PZ041UGmOPYC&pg=PA1004&dq=%22all%27ultimo+tuffo%22+s&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDp7GH_tvnAhXKz4UKHXZJDlsQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22all'ultimo%20tuffo%22%20s&f=false.

Comment: Su [Google Libri](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ5Wnt9bmh84jjs-Etld5oXW6CZGA%3A1582059272039&q=%22all%27ultimo+tuffo%22&oq=%22all%27ultimo+tuffo%22&aqs=heirloom-srp..) appare anche in contesti non sportivi.

Comment: Speriamo che arrivi una toscana o un toscano a spiegarcelo meglio :-)

Comment: Dimenticavo: Luti è toscano?

Comment: @Benedetta: Sì, è fiorentino.

Answer (score 1):

Questa è una risposta parziale perché fa riferimento soltanto al significato.

Adesso me n'accorgo che sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000445.jpg) si trova:

> – Ultimo tuffo: ultima azione o possibilità consenti­ta a qualcuno

con queste citazioni di Matteo Franco e di Macchiavelli:

> *M. Franco*, 1-18: Tu pensi tanto, Gigi, a far risposta; / non so 
>   s'e' s'è  che  troppo  t'abbaruffo,  /  aspetta  pure  un  altro  mio  rabuffo,  /  e  metti  ben,  ch'io  non  rifiuto  posta,  /  se  la  tuo' fantasia vie  non  s'arrosta,  /  questo  sie  certo  l’ultimo  tuo  tuffo. *Machia­velli*,
>     1-VI-392:  Io  stimo  che  questa  vostra  stanzia  di  costà  abia a essere l’ultimo vostro tuffo.

E ho visto anche che, alla voce ["lungo"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000307.jpg) di questo stesso dizionario, appare un esempio di uso della locuzione "all'ultimo tuffo" in una citazione di  Giuseppe Antonio Borgese (grassetto mio):

> Su  un margine del  foglietto aggiungeva  sbadatamente  per  il lungo,  come ricordandosene  **all’ultimo  tuffo**,  che  le  settecentocinquanta  lire  gliele  mandava  la  mamma.

Quindi, il senso di "all'ultimo tuffo" sarebbe effettivamente quello di "all'ultimo momento", ma con una sfumatura di "quando si ha l'ultima possibilità di fare qualcosa".

Comment: Scusate, ma non sempre è facile trovare le cose sul GDLI perché, come probabilmente avrete notato, i suoi [motori di ricerca](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11448) (?) non sempre funzionano del tutto bene.